# Spring 3 Form Validation is working for @NotNull but not working for @Size annotation

Tags: spring, validation

I am facing a problem with Spring form validation.
It works for @NotNull annotation but some how not working for @Size. I am attaching some code below. Thanks in advance.

```
    package com.doctor;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

    public class Doctor 
    {
        @NotNull(message="Cannot be Null")
        private String uname;


        @Size(min=1,max=8,message="Min 1 and Max 8")
        private String password;
        private String doctor_fname,doctor_lname,address,dept_id,experience,email,phone,resume,image;

        public String getUname() {
            return uname;
        }


        public void setUname(String uname) {
            this.uname = uname;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
....................
...................
```

DoctorController

```
package com.doctor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class DoctorController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/registerDoctor", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegisterForm(Model model) 
    {
        System.out.println("test");
        model.addAttribute(new Doctor());
        //return "register1";
        return "doctor/edit";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/registerDoctor", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDoctorformForm(@Valid Doctor doctor,BindingResult bindingresult) 
    {
        if(bindingresult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "doctor/edit";

        }
        else
        {               
            return "doctor/added";
        }


    }
}
```

Display page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>


    <h2>Create a Doctor account</h2>
    <sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="doctor"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="uname">User Name:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="uname"  /><br /> <sf:errors
                            path="uname" /> </td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="password">Password:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:password path="password" showPassword="true" />
                        <br /> <sf:errors
                            path="password" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="doctor_fname">First Name:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="doctor_fname" size="15" /><br /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="doctor_lname">Last Name:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="doctor_lname" size="15" /><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="address">Address:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="address" size="15" /><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="dept_id">Department:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="dept_id" size="15" /><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="experience">Experience:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="experience" size="15" /><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="email">Email Address:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="email" size="30" /> <small>In case
                            you forget something</small><br /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:label path="phone">Phone:</sf:label></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="phone" size="30" /> <small>In case
                            you forget something</small><br /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="resume">Resume:</label></td>
                    <td><input name="resume" type="file" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="image">Profile image:</label></td>
                    <td><input name="image" type="file" />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td><input name="commit" type="submit">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </sf:form>
```

[image: Output]

I don't understand why @Size for password is not working.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To exclude that your problem is not related to a not displayed message in the view, have you tryed to debug bindingresult?

Comment: Did a System.out.println(bindingresult.getAllErrors()); inside the controller if(bindingresult.hasErrors()) method...Got this result-----[Field error in object 'doctor' on field 'uname': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.doctor.uname,NotNull.uname,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [doctor.uname,uname]; arguments []; default message [uname]]; default message [Cannot be Null]]............................NOTHING came up for the password....

Comment: And if you print out the length of `username` from that `Doctor` object?

Comment: Your java code seems correct. Could you show us the view file for "edit"?

Comment: Tried this.......@RequestMapping(value="/registerDoctor", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String addDoctorformForm(@Valid Doctor doctor,BindingResult bindingresult) 
 {
  if(bindingresult.hasErrors())
  {
   System.out.println(bindingresult.getAllErrors());
   System.out.println("Doctor is ---->"+doctor);
   System.out.println("doctor.getUname()--------->"+doctor.getUname());
   System.out.println("doctor.getPassword()------->"+doctor.getPassword());..........Output was ....  Doctor is ---->com.doctor.Doctor@3c16417e
doctor.getUname()--------->null
doctor.getPassword()------->null

Comment: I have added my view page in the question... Thanks to all

Comment: Maybe @Size works only for non null strings. Try to set min=2 and input 1 character password

Comment: Make sure you have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in ur config

Comment: You need to use both `@NotNull` and `@Size` to validate null and length of a String according to the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html).

Comment: It works fine for me in Spring 4.0.2

Comment: Even if I enter 3 or more char in each of the text fields I am getting doctor.getUname()--------->null
doctor.getPassword()------->null

Comment: Shinchi Kai...  main issue is even if I am typing into the two text fields and submitting I am getting null    ---->>>   doctor.getUname()--------->null doctor.getPassword()------->null

Comment: Georgy Gobozov      i  had already added <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: Do you have a [multipartResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) in your spring configuration?

Comment: Thanks Shinichi Kai. I think the issue is here. I will update multipartResolver and will discuss again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it seems is you are using multipart form but I dont think I see a mention about multipartResolver. If needed here is how you can add it

```
<bean id="multipartResolver class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `null` is a valid value from `@Size`s point of view.

You need both annotations:

```
@Size(min=1,max=8,message="Min 1 and Max 8")
@NotNull
private String password;
```

<strike>*BTW: Your form is a simple form with no file upload, so there is no need to have `enctype="multipart/form-data" - I would remove it*</strike>

Comment: Ralph Please see the display page it contains file     
                   <input name="resume" type="file" />
                   <input name="image" type="file" />