# @Notnull and @Pattern in spring validation not working

Tags: java

I have a getter method like below:

```
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]{6}")
@XmlAttribute(name="CustomerID")
public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
```

message.properties has

```
NotEmpty.customerForm.customerId = CustomerID required
NotNull.customerForm.customerId = Customer ID required
Pattern.customerForm.customerId = Ship To Account must be a valid number
```

but even if i keep the CustomerId as blank or empty, it always displays the message Ship To Account must be a valid number , It never displays Customer ID required message.

Comment: shows us how do you validate the bean. Annotation like Pattern is not enough

Comment: @dit the application container validates the bean using the [JSR303 Bean validation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/) framework.

Comment: You will have to create your own [group sequence](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence) to stop on first error, if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi in Spring you will for example need Annotation Valid and BindingResult in you request mapping method

Comment: @dit for us, who are using Java EE CDI containers, Beans Validation is now part of its lifecycle so you just annotate and it'll validate your bean for you. No additional configs needed. :-)

Comment: He is working with spring, i still need more information... Annotation like Valid is not configuration... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895939/spring-3-form-validation-is-working-for-notnull-but-not-working-for-size-annot

Comment: I have used Spring form validation using Spring validation Framework. Everything works except if Pattern is present all other messages are suppressed and Pattern takes the priority even though its null or empty